# Computing all subsets of a vector in R

Tags: r

I want do write a small function which I can use for automatic feature selection in a logistic regression in R, by testing in a brute force manner all subsets of predictor variables and then evaluate via CV their classification performance.

Surprisingly I did not find a package which does this "all subset feature selection" and thus I would like to implement it myself.

Unfortunately my limited R knowledge makes me fail to write a loop which generates all subsets of a given vector and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat incernor

The [`bestglm` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestglm/vignettes/bestglm.pdf)  is what you are after

> The function bestglm selects the best subset of inputs for the glm family. The selec-
>   tion methods available include a variety of information criteria as well as cross-validation

The vignette goes through a number of examples.

```
library(bestglm)
data(SAHeart)
# using Cross valiation for selection
out<-bestglm(SAheart,IC  = 'CV', family=binomial, t = 10)
out
# CVd(d = 373, REP = 10)
# BICq equivalent for q in (0.190525988534159, 0.901583162187443)
# Best Model:
#                   Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)    -6.44644451 0.92087165 -7.000372 2.552830e-12
# tobacco         0.08037533 0.02587968  3.105731 1.898095e-03
# ldl             0.16199164 0.05496893  2.946967 3.209074e-03
# famhistPresent  0.90817526 0.22575844  4.022774 5.751659e-05
# typea           0.03711521 0.01216676  3.050542 2.284290e-03
# age             0.05046038 0.01020606  4.944159 7.647325e-07
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `drop1()` and `add1()` be helpful for your purpose? They come with the usual caution that automatic feature selection may not always be the most appropriate thing to do, but I presume you have made an informed choice on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste()` + `combn()`, e.g.

```
varnames <- c("a","b","c")
rhs <- unlist( sapply(1:length(varnames),function(k) apply(combn(varnames,k),2,paste,collapse=" + ") ) )
formulae <- as.formula( quote( paste("z ~", rhs) ) )
```

... but perhaps there is a more elegant way?